# Magento rewrite Core/Block/Template.php (Magento CE 1.8.1.0)

Tags: php, magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.8

I need to rewrite a Magento core block file, which full path is `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php`, in order to rewrite the `getTemplateFile()` function.
I have no problem with rewriting them, but the results are strange. In the `getTemplateFile()` function I have `$this->getTemplate()`, which returns a template. When I `print_r($this->getTemplate())` in the core block function, it gives me all the PHTMLs that are being loaded, while in the rewritten block I get only some of them. Do you have any ideas why is that happening? I am using Magento CE 1.8.1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rewrite the parent class of a block/model/helper in Magento, you can only rewrite a specific instance.

Here's how Magento's class rewriting works.  Whenever core Magento code (and well coded modules) instantiate an object, they do it with a factory method.

```
$layout->createBlock('core/template');
```

The `core/template` string is a class alias.  Magento uses this to lookup the actual class name to use.  By default, this is `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.  When you create a rewrite, you're telling Magento

> Hey, whenever you create a `core/template` block object?  Use my class instead.

The problem?  There are many blocks in Magento which **inherit** from the `core/template`.  When Magento instantiates one of these

```
$layout->createBlock('page/html_head')
```

It resolves to the class `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head`, which inherits from the core template class

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php
class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
}
```

In other words, there's no way for the rewrite system to know about your swapped in `core/template` class.

So when you say

> in the core block function, it gives me all the PHTMLs that are being loaded, while in the rewritten block I get only some of them

It sounds like you're seeing PHTMLs for the `core/template` blocks, but any blocks that inherit from `Mage_Core_Block_Template` are skipped.